# Internal representation of checkers board

Tags: python, pygame, board-game

I am creating a game of checkers using the but am struggling to find a good internal representation for the game. My initial thoughts were to store the game board in a 2d list, with 0=empty, 1=always empty, 2=team 1, 3=team 2. My second idea was to create a Piece class and append piece objects to an list, passing the x, y co-ordinates of each piece as I do this. Would anyone be able to suggest the best way to go about this. I later want to implement the min max algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your proposals can work.

- **A 2D list for the board** gives you the advantage that you can check whether a space contains a piece just by indexing with the coordinates of that space.

  But when you want to iterate over all of the pieces for a player (say, to check all their available moves, or evaluate the victory condition/heuristic), you have to iterate over the whole board. (Not dire, when it's only 64 iterations)
- **A list of piece objects** gives you the advantage that you can easily iterate over all of the pieces, particularly if you partition them by their owning player.

  But when you want to check whether a particular tile contains a piece, you have to iterate over the whole list checking for a piece with matching coordinates. (Not dire, when it's only 24 iterations at max)

You might notice that these pros and cons are exactly complementary: one representation excels where the other representation is weakest. So that gives you a third option: **use both**. That way you can use the most convenient structure for each task. You just need a little book-keeping to keep the two structures in-sync, so they never disagree about where the pieces are. It might seem redundant, but we're talking a matter of bytes here - this whole thing will fit in your CPU cache, so there's no need to be stingy with data structure memory here if it makes your other code simpler.